# Call Ubuntu settings with command line

Tags: command-line, 13.04, gnome-terminal

What command can I use in the terminal to open the settings options?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you're talking about "System Settings". Open it with:

```
gnome-control-center
```

Ubuntu 14.04 or later:

```
unity-control-center
```

[image]

Jump directly to a specific panel by passing its name to `gnome-control-center`:

```
gnome-control-center display
```

Ubuntu 14.04 or later:

```
unity-control-center display
```

[image]

The panel names are:

- background
- bluetooth
- color
- datetime
- display
- info
- keyboard
- mouse
- network
- online-accounts
- power
- printers
- region
- screen
- sound
- universal-access
- user-accounts
- wacom

Xfce:

```
xfce4-settings-manager
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there also a way to do so in lubuntu?